# Excel to PDF using VBA (Remove Blank Pages)

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, vba

I have a macro that spits out a PDF report. The PDF report should be of three pages. 
1. I have 4 extra blank pages in the PDF. How do I eliminate them?
2. How do I change the PDF report to Landscape mode in Macro?

Kush.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the print area to only include the pages you want if you haven't already?

Page Layout - Print Area - Set Print Area

2. Set the page layout to be landscape before printing